# What causes "Caught signal 11" errors using MPI?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I am trying to run simulations from R by using the doMPI package on a cluster.
For this I copy binaries to scratch of each worker in the foreach loop and afterwards input and output files are written from the simulations.

Those are the versions of the modules and R Packages I use:

```
openmpi 4.0.2
gcc 8.2.0
Rmpi 0.6-9
```

This is how I setup the foreach loop

```
suppressMessages(library(doMPI))
cl <- startMPIcluster()
registerDoMPI(cl)
res <- foreach(i=1:nrow(parameters_dt), .combine="c", .verbose = T,
               .export = c("function1", "parameters_dt")
) %dopar% {
    i_result <- function1(pars = parameters_dt[i,])
    return(i_result)
}
closeCluster(cl)
mpi.quit()
```

Most of the time everything works fine but I get errors like this randomly.

```
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address 0x4f9b3d0)
==== backtrace ====
    0  /cluster/spack/apps/linux-centos7-x86_64/gcc-8.2.0/ucx-1.6.1-f3pcfiiu6oav3fekzoxccr5irclwfiwv/lib/libucs.so.0(+0x1e874) [0x2affd00b5874]
    1  /cluster/spack/apps/linux-centos7-x86_64/gcc-8.2.0/ucx-1.6.1-f3pcfiiu6oav3fekzoxccr5irclwfiwv/lib/libucs.so.0(+0x1eb18) [0x2affd00b5b18]
    2  /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_fork+0x18d) [0x2affbfd03aad]
    3  /lib64/libc.so.6(_IO_proc_open+0xbc) [0x2affbfcae3dc]
    4  /lib64/libc.so.6(popen+0x5c) [0x2affbfcae66c]
    5  /cluster/spack/apps/linux-centos7-x86_64/gcc-8.2.0/r-4.0.2-mskxijfz5odg2oays2hzvr35rhxfw2nc/rlib/R/lib/libR.so(+0x276811) [0x2affbf1be811]
    6  /cluster/spack/apps/linux-centos7-x86_64/gcc-8.2.0/r-4.0.2-
...
```

I figured out that I can rerun the failed simulations on different workers. Thus I can rule out that the errors are caused by the simulation itself. But after a while all workers are gone and the whole process fails.

I have no idea where this error is coming from and I do not have the permission change any MPI settings. So, what can I do to solve this problem?
What are possible reasons for this error?

Comment: I don't know, but a guess is that the R code you're running uses a package that was compiled from C/C++/Fortran _and_ when that code ends up running on a cluster machine with an old CPU architecture, it fails. When you submit a new job, it might end up running on different machines, so then it might work.  See if you can reproduce the error with vanilla R code, e.g. `res <- foreach(i=1:10e3) %dopar% { mean(rnorm(100)) }`.  If you can't get it to crash with that, then that would indicated above old CPU-hardware problem.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Is there a way to know which packages could cause this issue? What exactly do you mean by old CPU architecture? I am running my simulations on modern HPC so I dont think that this is actually a problem. I also tried building the R packages from within MPI (although not its dependencies). But it did not solve the problem yet. I will check whether the vanilla Rcode thing will cause the issue as well. The programm I use is a .NET application. Could this also be caused by C# applications?

Comment: A CPU may be so old that it does not support CPU instructions like `AVX` or `AVX2`, i.e. `lscpu | grep Flags | grep -iF avx` comes out empty.  We're talking about CPUs from ~2015 or so.  Some HPC systems might have both old and new hardware. This was just an idea of one thing to rule out.